# WPF MediaElement: SpeedRatio not working for .m4a files?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, mediaelement, m4a

I'm working with a simple mediaplayer based on [this msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.speedratio.aspx) where the user can control volume, playback speed (`SpeedRatio`) and seek (`Position`) using 3 sliders.

Everything works correctly when I play `.mp3` files, but as soon as I play an `.m4a` file the song playback speed, controlled by the `MediaElement.SpeedRatio`, is ignored. Volume and seek still works and the audio is working.

Questions:

- Are there any logical explanations for this?
- Any known solutions/workarounds to this problem? The speedratio is essential in my application.

Thanks,
Avada

Comment: same for MTS and M2TS files... I think it is about encoding...

Comment: in which format is the audio stream inside the m4a container encoded?

Answer (score 0):

check this out:
[MediaElement Speedratio not linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957742/mediaelement-speedratio-not-linear)