# MediaElement Speedratio not linear

Tags: .net, wpf, mediaelement

I have a `MediaElement` which I use to display movies. I would like to have precise control of the speed at which these movies are played. For this purpose I used the `SpeedRatio` property on `MediaElement`.

The problem I have is that it does not seem to be linear. At speedratio 2 it plays at almost 4x speed (ie 40 seconds play in 10 seconds) and speedratio 0.5 plays at almost 0.25x speed (ie 10 seconds play in 40 seconds). This is an approximation, can anyone clarify? The documentation does not explain.

Also when playing at a `SpeedRatio` other than 1x the movie seems to jitter. I have added a label that displays the position in the movie and it is very obvious that it does not run smooth. Are there other solutions to try?

I have experience with XNA and it might give better performance. However, for the sake of keeping the project simple I would like to keep the project entirely WPF based. The menu system is made with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/dbdc8981-e888-491f-98ab-7a9794f352d3/), the `SpeedRatio` is highly dependent on the codec of the video. I would assume that the codec you're using doesn't support smooth fast forward or rewind.