# Implementing Slow SpeedRatio MediaElement for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I'm just curious if there is a way to slow down the speed ratio of the MediaElement in Windows Phone 7, I tried by seeking into the media stream each xxx millisecond but this is not working all the time, sometimes the element does not show the frames and stops updating its content.
Any trick to pass around this limitation on Windows Phone 7

Comment: Seems like it depends on the codec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957742/mediaelement-speedratio-not-linear/6960765#6960765

Comment: The problem is that this property is not available at all in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7

Comment: The SmoothStreamingMediaElement control might be worth using here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SmoothStreamingMediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead and use its [SetPlaybackRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement.setplaybackrate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

Comment: I tried but it does not seem to be working with video files with build action = content, I tried by getting the absolute file URI of the video files saved in the install folder using a reflection hack, the video plays but unfortunately, when I use SetPlaybackRate, an exception is thrown saying that I can not use this method if the video is set to Source Property instead of SmoothStreamingSource, I tried by changing to SmoothStreaming source but the video does not play at all.